# When is the symbol table for this program built

Tags: yacc, lexical-analysis

When I run make on the following Makefile, when is the symbol table built, if it even is?

```
LEX = flex
YACC = yacc
CC = gcc

calcu: y.tab.o lex.yy.o
    $(CC) -o calcu y.tab.o lex.yy.o -ly -lfl

y.tab.c y.tab.h: parser.y
    $(YACC) -d parser.y

y.tab.o: y.tab.c parser.h
    $(CC) -c y.tab.c

lex.yy.o: y.tab.h lex.yy.c 
    $(CC) -c lex.yy.c

lex.yy.c: calclexer.l parser.h
    $(LEX) calclexer.l

clean:
    rm *.o
    rm *.c
    rm calcu
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`make` doesn't build symbol tables (obviously the compilers and linkers it invokes will have to do that!).  I'll assume you're referring to whatever the resulting `calcu` binary does wrt its input, instead.

If any such thing as a "symbol table" is ever built by `calcu`, it will be by code you inserted into `parser.y` that gets moved over into `yacc.tab.c`; as to **when**, it will be during the course of a `calcu` run over whatever its input is -- incrementally, as each syntax production including "symbol-table building code" matches.

Comment: I think the symbol table is completely built before the program is even run.